# How can I assign a property to an attribute

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to assign a property string to below attribute.

```
[ExtractKeyAttribute(**"Extraction"**)]

public class Extract
{
  ....
}
```

so extraction is my string but I don't want hard code into there. Any suggestions on better way to assign

Comment: Can you put the attribute on the property itself?

Comment: How to call what? It looks like you have a property that defines what should be extracted as a key, right? So maybe if you have a `KeyName` attribute and placed it on the property, then whatever is doing the extraction can look for your `KeyName` attribute on the class's properties, then get the name of the key from whichever property has that attribute.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Yes that make sense mate...I've given into const string and assigning to attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this.

Attribute values *must* be constant expressions. The values are baked into the compiled code. If you don't want to use a constant expression, you can't use an attribute... and you possibly shouldn't. It may mean you're using attributes when you should be using a different approach.

You might want to read Eric Lippert's blog post on [properties vs attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/02/properties-vs-attributes.aspx).

Of course, you don't have to use a string literal there. You could have:

```
[ExtractKey(ExtractionKeys.Extraction)]
...


public static class ExtractionKeys
{
    public const string Extraction = "Extraction";
}
```

... but it's still a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and let me check thru link

Comment: @user1990395: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Please clarify your comment, and I may be able to answer.

Comment: Just for completeness, another common(-ish) option for avoiding hard literals is to subclass the attribute such that the subclass can resolve the actual value at runtime in regular code.

Comment: +1 for the very interesting link. I should really find and read everything that Eric Lippert has ever written. ;-)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, My intention was to change these attribute strings in future as well so I can maintain these string values in separate class file or config file. I need to run the classes based on these strings in Attribute. In future Just i need to change the string value only rather changing into class file.

Comment: @user1990395: Well bear in mind that if they're in different assemblies, the string value will have been copied into the binary declaring the attribute. Be *very* careful here.

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly Jon. Yes they're in different assemblies.I'm really worrying about this.

Comment: @user1990395: Then basically you'd need to rebuild both assemblies if you ever changed the values of the string constants.

Comment: @JonSkeet :-) of course i can do that. Better I can just give hard coded value as string into Attribute. BTW thanks for the link. appreciated mate

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you say you have all (string) values in a static class. Is your static class a class with readonly properties? I mean, do the values change? If not, replace some of those properties in your static class with const strings values. U can use these values to set your attribute.

So...

```
static class MyClass
{
     public string MyValue {get;}
}
```

would become:

```
static class MyClass
{
     public const string MyValue= "MyValue";
}
```

Now your attribute can be set as follows:

```
[ExtractKey(MyClass.MyValue)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the property of your attribute during runtime, then you can do this with this code:

```
ExtractKeyAttribute myAttribute = typeof(Extract).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExtractKeyAttribute), false)[0] as ExtractKeyAttribute;
myAttribute.MyValue = "MyRunTimeValue";
```